# Find/Remove oldest file in directory

Tags: python, file-io, path

I am trying to delete oldest file in directory when number of files reaches a threshold.

```
list_of_files = os.listdir('log')    

if len([name for name in list_of_files]) == 25:
    oldest_file = min(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    os.remove('log/'+oldest_file)
```

Problem: The issue is in min method. list_of_files does not contain full path, so it is trying to search file in current directory and failing. How can I pass directory name ('log') to min()?

Comment: Have you looked at `os.path.abspath`? And errr, isn't this what facilities such as logrotate are for?

Comment: `sorted(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)[0]` gives you the oldest file.

Comment: sorted is failing for same reason..

Comment: @srig that's not the issue here, and using `min()` over the list instead is efficient of sorting the entire list to take the first is rather inefficient

Comment: Thanks for pointing to logrotate.. new at python.. gonna look at it.. but its good if I could understand what's wrong here..

Comment: adding os.path.abspath in key gives this error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getctime'

Comment: @JonClements, agree.

Comment: @user2407394 apply `os.path.abspath` to `oldest_file` - then `os.remove` that - is that what you're doing?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get.. Its failing at min() because list_of_files does not contain full path.. where can I add os.path.abspath to oldest_file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
list_of_files = os.listdir('log')
full_path = ["log/{0}".format(x) for x in list_of_files]

if len(list_of_files) == 25:
    oldest_file = min(full_path, key=os.path.getctime)
    os.remove(oldest_file)
```

Comment: This'll work if the listdir and the log file are in the *same* place - it's better to  (generally and to not repeat the use of where the file comes from) use the `os.path.abspath` to retrieve the full path name of the file and then `os.remove` that

Answer (score 6):

`os.listdir` will return *relative* paths - those are ones that are relative to your current/present working directory/context of what your Python script was executed in (you can see that via `os.getcwd()`).

Now, the `os.remove` function expects a *full path*/*absolute path* - shells/command line interfaces infer this and do it on your behalf - but Python doesn't. You can get that via using `os.path.abspath`, so you can change your code to be (and since os.listdir returns a list anyway, we don't need to add a list-comp over it to be able to check its length)...:

```
list_of_files = os.listdir('log')    

if len(list_of_files) >= 25:
    oldest_file = min(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    os.remove(os.path.abspath(oldest_file))
```

That keeps it generic as to where it came from - ie, whatever was produced in the result of `os.listdir` - you don't need to worry about prepending suitable file paths.

Comment: Actually, this was not the issue.. os.remove correctly takes relative path (python 3.7).. The problem is inside min().. list_of_files contains only file name "abc.log" but not the relative path "log/abc.com".. so min() is unable to find key..

Comment: The script is being executed from parent directory of 'log' directory.. Perhaps I didn't phrase the question that way..

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to achieve the same as what you are trying to achieve. and was facing a similar issue related to `os.path.abspath()`
I am using a windows system with `python 3.7`

and the issue is that `os.path.abspath()` gives one folder up location
replace **"Yourpath"** and with the path of folder in which your file is and code should work fine

```
import os
import time

oldest_file = sorted([ "Yourpath"+f for f in os.listdir("Yourpath")], key=os.path.getctime)[0]

print (oldest_file)
os.remove(oldest_file)
print ("{0} has been deleted".format(oldest_file))`
```

There must be some cleaner method to do the same
I'll update when I get it

Answer (score 3):

The glob library gives on the one hand full paths and allows filtering for file patterns. The above solution resulted in the directory itself as the oldest file, which is not that what I wanted. For me, the following is suitable (a blend of glob and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941703/4776697) of @Ivan Motin)

`import glob`

`sorted(glob.glob("/home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg"), key=os.path.getctime)[0]`

Comment: for me worked this: 
print (sorted(glob.glob("*.json"), key=os.path.getctime)[-1])

Answer (score 1):

using comprehension (sorry, couldn't resist):

```
oldest_file = sorted([os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir('log') ], key=os.path.getctime)[0]
```